# Line breaks for cases environment in two column

Tags: two-column, cases

I have case environments that breaks into the other column when used in two column.

[image]

How can I break the cases to prevent the intrusion? This is the source code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $range(type)$ returns the value range of $type$. 
\item $related(key, type)$ returns a set of tuple ($key$, $type$) that is
  related to the input $key$ and $type$.
\item $type(key)$ returns a $type$ of an input $key$.  

\item zero detection function $z(key)$ 
\[
z(key) =
   \begin{cases}
     true, & \text{if}\ \forall i \in hash(key), table(i) = 0\\
     false, & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases} 
\]
\item $retrieve(key)$
\[ 
retrieve(key) =
   \begin{cases}
     \perp_{s}, & \text{if $z(key)$ is true}\\
     mask(key) \oplus \bigoplus_{i \in hash(key)} table[i], & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases} 
\]
\end{itemize}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crampy, but with such equations in two column, you don't have  options.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $range(type)$ returns the value range of $type$.
\item $related(key, type)$ returns a set of tuple ($key$, $type$) that is
  related to the input $key$ and $type$.
\item $type(key)$ returns a $type$ of an input $key$.

\item zero detection function $z(key)$
\[
z(key) =
   \begin{cases}
     true, & \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}\text{if}\ \forall i \in hash(key),\\ table(i) = 0\end{array}\\
     false, & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}
\]
\item $retrieve(key)$
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
retrieve\\
(key)
\end{array} =
   \begin{cases}
     \perp_{s}, & \mkern-13mu\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}\text{if $z(key)$}\\ \text{is true}\end{array}\\
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     mask(key) \oplus \\
     \bigoplus_{i \in hash(key)} table[i],
     \end{array} & \mkern-13mu\text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}
\]
\end{itemize}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is still a bit overfull but more or less fits, adjust to taste. Note you should never use the math italic font for multi-letter identifiers, the font is specifically designed so that adjacent letters look like separate variables and *not* a word.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $range(type)$ returns the value range of $type$. 
\item $related(key, type)$ returns a set of tuple ($key$, $type$) that is
  related to the input $key$ and $type$.
\item $type(key)$ returns a $type$ of an input $key$.  

\item zero detection function $z(key)$ 
\[
z(\mathit{key}) =
   \begin{cases}
     \mathit{true}, & \parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright
   if $\forall i \in \mathit{hash}(\mathit{key}), \mathit{table}(i) = 0$}\\
     \mathit{false}, & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases} 
\]
\item $\mathit{retrieve}(\mathit{key})$
\begin{multline}
\mathit{retrieve}(\mathit{key}) \\
   {}=\begin{cases}
     \perp_{s}, & \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright
       if $z(\mathit{key})$ is true}\\
     \parbox[c]{3cm}{$\mathit{mask}(\mathit{key}) \oplus \bigoplus_{i \in \mathit{hash}(\mathit{key})} \mathit{table}[i], $}& \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases} 
\end{multline}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```